# How do I show additional clocks in the new Windows 10 clock?

Tags: windows-10-preview, clock, time-zone

With the old clocks we can view at most two additional clocks. However the new clock interface in Windows 10 only displays the current system clock. To view the time in other places I must click on Additional Clocks which is very inconvenient.

[image: Windows 10 clock]

How can I view more than one clock with this?

Comment: If there isn't a checkbox labled "show this clock" then this functionality either has been removed or is not yet been enabled in Windows 10.

Comment: I have clock 2 showing on top of the main time.  Im trying to remove it!

Comment: What's wrong with this? This was with the Windows 10 preview and the fact that it doesn't appear anymore with Windows 10 RTM doesn't mean that it is off topic or wrong and deserve a downvote

Comment: @Jon maybe you've never worked with people in different timezones. If it appears then someone must have enabled it, so it's easy to turn off. At the time I posted this it's not possible to show more clocks

Comment: what?  what has working with people have to do with someone changing things on my computer?  Who enabled it so I can ask him to turn it off?  Or just how do I turn it off?  If its not possible to do how did this someone turn it on as me must have?

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Date and time settings', then at the bottom of Related settings click 'Add clocks for different time zones'. This brings up the Additional Clocks tab of the old style Date and Time control panel.

Comment: This was fixed with the current build. My question is for some preview versions